# « Visiter » vs « rendre visite à » ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Est-ce que la signification est complètement la même ? Les phrases ci-dessous sont-elles toutes possibles (les deux premières pour des personnes, les deux suivantes pour des lieux) ?

1. Je vais visiter mon grand-père.
2. Je vais rendre visite à mon grand-père.
3. Je vais visiter un musée.
4. Je vais rendre visite à un musée.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tu rends visite à quelqu'un mais tu visites un endroit.

Dans ton exemple, tu peux rendre visite à ton grand père mais pas le visiter (ce qui peut par ailleurs avoir une connotation ... pas vraiment voulue :), et tu ne rends pas visite au musée mais tu vas le visiter.

Comment: C'est plus complexe que ça.  Un médecin visite ses malades et moi, pendant les vacances, je vais visiter ma famille restée en Belgique.

Comment: Un médecin rend visite à ses malades car il va les voir chez eux (c'est sous-entendu, d'où la notion de lieu). Pour ton second exemple, il me surprend car je dis "je rend visite à ma famille en Belgique" plus que "je visite ma famille en Belgique"

Comment: Voir http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/visiter même si le TFLi donne l'impression inverse que _visiter qqun_ est d'usage plus général que ce que je le pense (l'Academie indique bien par contre que _rendre visite_ est plus commun).

Comment: A vrai dire quand je lis "je vais visiter mon grand-père", je sous-entend que le grand-père est malade, mais peut-être cela est-il lié au "médecin qui visite ses malades"

Comment: Pour être tout à fait complet, on peut _visiter un ami_. Cette utilisation est désuette, mais parfaitement juste. Voir la première définition du [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/visiter).

Answer (score 5):

Tu "peux" éventuellement dire "je visite ma famille" même si "je rend visite à ma famille." est plus correct.
Par contre vaut mieux éviter d'utiliser "visiter" en parlant d'une fille, car cela pourrait avoir une connotation un peu sexuelle.

Answer (score 4):

Je suis Coach de langue française pour anglophones et hispanophones, et je connais bien ce problème car dans la langue anglaise comme dans la langue espagnole on peut « visiter » quelqu'un. Je dois sans cesse rappeler qu'en français on « rend visite à quelqu'un » et on « visite un lieu ». En fait, l'utilisation du verbe visiter avec une personne en français semble possible simplement par déformation de « traduction francisée »; c'est-à-dire que les anglophones et les hispanophones qui apprennent le français adoptent le verbe visiter comme dans leur propre langue (avec des personnes comme avec des lieux) et les français qui les entendent et qui ne se posent pas la question, répètent... très souvent mes élèves me demandent si je suis sûre car ils ont déjà entendu des français utiliser le verbe pour les personnes. La langue française est très riche, parfois trop, et les étrangers essaient de se simplifier la vie...

Comment: C’est faux : le TLFi propose un exemple d’utilisation de « visiter quelqu’un » qui remonte à 1859. Et un exemple de Proust, en 1922.

Comment: @Édouard Je viens de faire la remarque sur la réponse acceptée. Cela existe mais c'est désuet et par conséquent risque d'être mal compris de nos jours, surtout avec les connotations qui peuvent s'y rattacher aujourd'hui.

Answer (score 4):

Le fait que l'expression « Visiter quelqu'un » soit désuète ne la rend pas incorrecte et en interdit encore moins l'usage.

Entendre « Je vais visiter ma famille qui vit dans le ..., etc. » est même plutôt courant. Il y a quelque chose de plus solennel dit de cette façon.

« Rendre visite » suggère, elle, que la durée de la visite ne sera pas très longue.

Comment: Personne n'interdit de dire *je vais visiter ma famille* et tout le monde comprendra. Le fait est qu'on ne dit plus souvent non plus *je vais rendre visite à ma famille* en français courant. C'est plutôt, *je vais passer voir ma famille* ou *passer leur dire bonjour* ou quelque chose du même style.

Answer (score 1):

D'après l'ouvrage *Larousse Thématique : Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française* **visiter** peut se dire aussi pour **"rendre visite**". Les exemples ci-dessous sont donnés (tirés par le dictionnaires : Littré, Acad., Larousse du XXe siècle).

> Visiter ses chefs. Visiter un ami. Visiter un malade.

Selon le livre, il se dit surtout pour les malades, les pauvres, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Il suffit de regarder le dico :
http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/visiter/82212

Comment: C'est un peu léger comme réponse.