# Why is 'rends' needed in this sentence

Tags: grammaire, expressions, traduction, usage, compléments

I am trying to say:

> This is the first time I visit her

This is how I thought it should be written:

> C'est la première fois que je lui visite

This is how it is actually written:

> C'est la première fois que je lui *rends* visite

When I check the meaning of 'rends' it means "return/restore"

Can someone explain how does it fit in the above sentence and why is it actually needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence is wrong.

> *C'est la première fois que je visite le musée, le cinéma, etc.*

That is, **visiter quelque chose**.

> *C'est la première fois que je **rends visite à** Georges (man)/Hélène (woman)/. => C'est la première fois que je lui rends visite* (and not *visiter* !!!).

That is *rendre visite à quelqu'un*.

[Google Translate actually gives the [correct translation](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=fr&text=This%20is%20the%20first%20time%20I%20visit%20her).]

Man or woman is immaterial, inasmuch as the expression is *rendre visite à quelqu'un* (googling *complément d'objet indirect* or French Dative).

For a group of people (immaterial of sex) it would be:

> C'est la première fois que je **leur** rends visite.

One should learn "rendre visite à" as a fixed expression (*expression figée*). There is no reason to break it into different parts. In expressions of this kind one should not isolate, for instance, *rendre* from *visite* and so on.

---

In compound tenses there is no need of agreement of the past participle. That is, one would say in passé composé

> C'est la première fois que je lui ai rendu/leur ai rendu visite.

---

This is the basic usage; sufficient for *débutants/faux débutants* of the French language. For more details see here:

[« Visiter » vs « rendre visite à » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/visiter-vs-rendre-visite-%C3%A0#targetText=Tu%20rends%20visite%20%C3%A0%20quelqu,mais%20tu%20vas%20le%20visiter).

As @jlliagre clarifies:

> You write "This is the first time I visit her (a girl). That's why *lui* is needed". In fact, should ***lui*** has been needed, that would actually be *le* at the masculine (*c'est la première fois que je **le** visite*) and *elle* at the feminine (*c'est la première fois que je **la** visite*). Still incorrect though, as *je lui rends visite* is the right expression.

Also

> *C'est la première fois que je la visite* is grammatically correct but if said by a native French speaker referring to a girl, will likely be understood as a joke or (possibly) with a sexual connotation.

and

> In any case, we do not use that much the verb *visiter* here. The translation that first comes to mind is *C'est la première fois que je vais (la voir) chez elle*.

---

According to the book Larousse Thématique : Dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française

> (...) visiter peut se dire aussi pour "rendre visite".

In particular the following examples are given (taken by Littré, Académie, Larousse du XXe siècle).

> Visiter ses chefs. Visiter un ami. Visiter un malade.

Still from the same book

> il (i.e. visite) se dit surtout pour les malades, les pauvres, etc.

Comment: The sentence is in the middle of a paragraph. I am trying to say: This is the first time I visit her (a girl). Thats why lui is needed.

Comment: @Mhmd As I wrote : C'est la premiere fois que je lui rends visite. Man or woman is immaterial, inasmuch as the expression rendre visite à quelqu'un (complément d'objet indirect).

Comment: I understand. so I should just remove the 'r' in visiter. but can you tell me what is the significance of rends in the sentence.

Comment: @Mhmd Try to learn this as a fixed expression. In French one would say "expression figée". Don't try to isolate rendre from visite.

Comment: @Mhmd You write "This is the first time I visit her (a girl). That's why lui is needed". In fact, should *lui* has been needed, that would actually be *elle* in that case giving *c'est la première fois que je **la** visite*. Still incorrect though, as *je lui rends visite* is the right expression.

Comment: @jlliagre Also I added an answer in an old relevant question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/visiter-vs-rendre-visite-%c3%a0

Comment: @Dimitris *C'est la première fois que je la visite* is grammatically correct but if said by a native French speaker referring to a girl, will likely be understood as a joke.

Comment: @jlliagre Je la visite does it have any sexual connotation ?

Comment: Possibly indeed. In any case, we do not use that much the verb *visiter* here. The translation that first comes to mind is ***C'est la première fois que je vais (la voir) chez elle***.

Comment: @jlliagre Should I live the answer as it is or add also **'Cest la première fois que je vais (la voir) chez elle**? (Thanks for the comments!)

Comment: *C'est la première fois que je lui rends visite* is fine and idiomatic but feel free to add my suggestion as a less formal alternative.

Comment: Why do you use the plural in *Your sentence**s are** wrong* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Initialement l'OP a écrit : C'est la première fois que je lui visite**r** et C'est la première fois que je lui rends visite**r**.

Comment: Okay, that was off-topic and possibly a typo. You should use the singular now the OP corrected it.

Comment: @jlliagre Déjà corrigé:-)!

Comment: By the way *quelqu'une* is almost unused, *quelqu'un* being neutral and indefinite. Most people would consider *rendre viste à quelqu'une* incorrect or kind of a joke.

Comment: @jlliagre Je viens de le modifier. Merci encore !